# Trying to add delete button in order to delete users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, controller, destroy

I am following along with Michael Hartls tutorial and I am trying to add the destroy action in order to delete users as admin. However, the link is not displaying under users name. I am also using Devise, not sure if that matters. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Controller/users**

```
def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted."
    redirect_to users_path
  end


  def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end
```

**_users.html**

```
<li>
  <class= "round-image-50"><%= image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
  <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

**Routes**

```
devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users

  resources :posts
  resources :users

  get "users/show"


  get 'feed', to: 'posts#index', as: :feed
  get "about" => "pages#about"
  root "pages#home"

  match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', via: :get
```

**Migration**

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :admin
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess the problem is this `!current_user?(user)`.Try removing it from the `if` condition.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Thank you for helping me out on all my problems. @Pavan

Comment: `admin user` is a `current_user`?

Comment: yes. I am the current user, I am also the admin.

Comment: Hmm,then this condition `<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>` should be `<% if current_user.admin? && current_user?(user) %>` right.

Comment: I tried that and still nothing. I'm trying to move it some things around. I'm lost

Comment: @Pavan I was able to get the link to display only for the admin however, now when I click on the delete link I get the error: Unknown action.The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController. I thought I had it!


  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. The below code needed to go on my user index page instead not the _user.html page. Thank you for your help @Pavan

```
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
  <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```